# How to convert an object to JSON correctly in Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: json, post, typescript, angular

I'm creating an Angular 2 simple CRUD application that allows me to CRUD products. I'm trying to implement the post method so I can create a product. My backend is an ASP.NET Web API. I'm having some trouble because when transforming my Product object to JSON it is not doing it correctly. The 
expected JSON should be like this:

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "Laptop",
  "Price": 2000
}
```

However, the JSON sent from my application is this:

```
{  
   "product":{  
      "Name":"Laptop",
      "Price":2000
   }
}
```

Why is it adding a "product" in the beginning of the JSON? What can I do to fix this? My code:

product.ts

```
export class Product {

    constructor(
        public ID: number,
        public Name: string,
        public Price: number
    ) { }   
}
```

product.service.ts

```
import {Injectable}   from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {Product} from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    private productsUrl = 'http://localhost:58875/api/products';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.productsUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <Product[]>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    addProduct(product: Product) {                
        let body = JSON.stringify({ product });            
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.productsUrl, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }
}
```

create-product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { Product } from '../product'
import { ProductService } from '../product.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-create-product',
    templateUrl: 'create-product.html',
    styleUrls: ['create-product.css'],
})
export class CreateProductComponent {

    product = new Product(undefined, '', undefined);
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    addProduct() {            
        if (!this.product) { return; }
        this.productService.addProduct(this.product)
            .subscribe(
            product => this.product,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

create-product.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Create Product</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="addProduct()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="product.Name" name="Name"  #name="ngModel">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Price">Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="product.Price" name="Price">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addProduct">Add Product</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In your product.service.ts you are using stringify method in a wrong way..

Just use

```
JSON.stringify(product)
```

instead of

```
JSON.stringify({product})
```

i have checked your problem and after this it's working absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks, man! You've been on fire these past few days! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment Bro  n let me know if u get any further issues... i will be there to help u :)

Comment: what is the difference between JSON.stringify(product)  and .JSON.stringify({product})

Comment: The difference can be seen clearly by the exapmle:-
let say product = {'name':'laptop','price':2000}
then, if u do JSON.stringify(product) that gives out as "{"name":"laptop","price":2000}"
But if u do JSON.stringify({product}) this gives out as "{"product":{"name":"laptop","price":2000}}"
so i hope the difference between these 2 are clear :)

Comment: How is this correct? You're converting this to a string not a json.  Please see   answer below. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))

Comment: @DavidHaddad Are you serious? How could you send a object in body of a rest api call without stringify it?

Comment: I'm referring to the the question title whcih is about creating a json object and you'll need to do json.parse to get an actual object that you can use at runtime. What you're doing is converting a json object to a string version of itself.

Comment: Don't just check the title, please refer to the complete problem of the people what they are trying to do and where they are struck so that we can help them 

Answer (score 36):

You'll have to parse again if you want it in actual JSON:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
```

Answer (score 28):

If you are solely interested in outputting the JSON somewhere in your HTML, you could also use a pipe inside an interpolation. For example:

```
<p> {{ product | json }} </p>
```

I am not entirely sure it works for every AngularJS version, but it works perfectly in my Ionic App (which uses Angular 2+).

Answer (score 12):

Because you're encapsulating the product again. Try to convert it like so:

```
let body = JSON.stringify(product);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Tested and working in Angular 9.0**

If you're getting the data using API

```
array: [];

ngOnInit()    {
this.service.method()
.subscribe(
    data=>
  {
    this.array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.object));
  }
)
```

}

You can use that array to print your results from API data in html template.

Like

```
<p>{{array['something']}}</p>
```