# How to covert JSON Object (angular2)?

Tags: angular

my response from server is something like this :

```
  {
    "message": " list received successfully",
    "success": "true",
    "data": {
    "_list": [{
      "id": "",
      "name": "",
      "image_url": null,
      "is_occupation": true
      },
      {
      "id": "",
      "name": "",
      "image_url": null,
      "is_occupation": true
      }
    ],
    "responseCode":"",
  }
```

How to show this data in list(html) in angular2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an object to JSON correctly in Angular 2 with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372134/how-to-convert-an-object-to-json-correctly-in-angular-2-with-typescript)

Comment: He doesn't want to convert it (title is misleading) but rather just print out properties of an object in list as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
selector:'list',
template: `
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>image_url</th>
        <th>is_occupation</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of responseData.data._list">
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.image_url}}</td>
            <td>{{data.is_occupation}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`
})
export class List { 

  const responseData={
   "message": " list received successfully",
   "success": "true",
   "data": {
   "_list": [
   {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "image_url": null,
    "is_occupation": true
   },
   {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "image_url": null,
    "is_occupation": true
   }],
   "responseCode":"",
  };

 }
```