# How to convert an object to JSON list in Angular 2?

Tags: json, angular

I am creating a form which outputs JSON. I need some fields as a JSON list.
For eg:

```
{"Name":"sam","age":"21","Friends":[{"Name":"bob","age":"21"}]}
```

But, when I use this code `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))`

I end up getting something like this

```
{"Name":"sam","age":"21","Friends":{"Name":"bob","age":"21"}}
```

The `[]` is missing. How do I make a JSON list?

ps: I am new to web development, forgive me if the question is silly.

my `app.component.html`

```
<div class="container">

  <form #payloadForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(payloadForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" ngModel  value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>age</label>
      <input type="text" name="age" ngModel value="" class="form-control">
    </div>

  <div ngModelGroup="Friends">
<label>Friend Name</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" ngModel  value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>age</label>
      <input type="text" name="age" ngModel value="" class="form-control">
    </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

my `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onSubmit(value: any){
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
      console.log("String");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `stringify` and `parse` at the same time? They cancel out each other and you still get `value` as the result. So, you might as well use `value` straight away.

Comment: Also, what is the value of `value`?

Comment: You misread the output. What you're showing isn't a valid JS object, and isn't valid JSON either. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-st8huq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. For actual help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I followed this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372134/how-to-convert-an-object-to-json-correctly-in-angular-2-with-typescript/38373028

Comment: @JBNizet Please look at my code and comment on it

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Form content is passed as `value`

Comment: You're using a template-driven form. The principle of such a form is that form controls are bound to a model object that you're creating in your component. So you need to have a person object in your component, containing an array of friends, and you of course need a loop (ngFor) in your template allowing to display/enter each element of this array of friends. The alternative is a reactive form, using a FormArray: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much for your input. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can JSON.parse() that complete JSON string. After that you can simply access the array from that object you got returned from JSON.parse().