# Angular TreeView with dynamic childs

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview, syncfusion

I need to generate a treeView with a dynamic data, I am working with the component of syncfusion https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/treeview/getting-started/

The problem I have is that the object I receive is not complete, but the "children" are generated as you go accessing through the id. So I get to show the initial categories but never associate the children.

This is the app.component.html

```
       <div class="control-section" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class='col-lg-6 nested-data'>
            <div class='content'>
                <h4>Categorías</h4>
                <ejs-treeview id="tree" #tree [checkedNodes]='checkedNodes' [fields]='fields'>
                </ejs-treeview>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is app.componente.ts

```
treeData!: object;
    public fields = {
      dataSource: this.treeData,
      id: 'SID',
      text: 'Name',
      child: 'Children'
    };
    public showCheckBox = true;
    public checkedNodes: string[] = ['70', '1', '88'];


 
    
    ngOnInit(): void {

      if(this.request){
        const res = this.service.getCategory(this.request);
        if(res){
          this.Cats= res;

          res.subscribe(tree =>{
            this.treeData =  tree.Category
            this.fields= {
              dataSource: this.treeData,
              id: tree.SID,
              text: 'Name',
              child: 'Children'
            };
          })
  
         }
      }
```

In this way I show the initial categories but it never shows the daughters because it detects that it is an empty array...Now I would have to click on a category to obtain the id to call the service again and show the daughter categories. I can't do it because the information is only accessible from a subscribe, I can't save it as a global variable either.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In TreeView Hierarchical datasource type, you can able to map the [child](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/treeview/fieldsSettingsModel/#child) nodes for the nodes using child property in [fields](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/treeview/#fields). However, the [dataSource](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/treeview/fieldsSettingsModel/#datasource) mapped for the child property should be same with same set of properties.

You can refer to the below documentation to know more about TreeView component.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/treeview/data-binding/#hierarchical-data

By default, the TreeView rendering requires a data source in the form of a JSON structure. You can display any type of data in TreeView if it follows the JSON structure. This is the default TreeView structure behavior. You need to convert the data you obtained from the service to JSON format. You can refer to the below blog for reference.

[How to convert an object to JSON correctly in Angular 2 with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372134/how-to-convert-an-object-to-json-correctly-in-angular-2-with-typescript)

If issue still persists, share a simple issue replicated sample to validate on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I do not understand is how to make a call to a node to get the ID from there to return to make a call to the api and load the child nodes ... With the events I can not capture the id of each node so I have not created the child nodes for the tree view.